# Google Analytics API fromdate, todate. How to start from when started tracking?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm new to C# and I am creating a console application which connects to Google Analytics using the API. I have got it so it writes the data grabbed in the console and exports it to a CSV however I have specified dates here:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        Authenticate();
        **getVisits("2013-01-01", "2015-01-28");**
        PercentInc();
    }
```

I need it to start from when I first started tracking the website without entering manually.
Reason: The idea of this tool is too loop through a database table consisting of the GA ids and then write the data into a CSV document but for future it will be put in a database.

Here is the getVisits function

```
static void getVisits(string fromDate, string toDate) {
        DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = service.Data.Ga.Get(
           "ga:" + websiteCode,
           fromDate,
           toDate,
           "ga:users");
        request.Dimensions = "ga:year,ga:month,ga:day";
        var data = request.Execute();

        foreach (var row in data.Rows) {
            DateTime visitDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(row[0]), int.Parse(row[1]), int.Parse(row[2]));
            int numVisits = int.Parse(row[3]);
            if (numVisits == 0) {

            }
            string filePath = "exports/" + clientGAID + ".csv";
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
            Console.WriteLine("Completed [" + visitDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "] Client: " + clientGAID + " {" + numVisits + "}");
            if (!File.Exists(filePath)) {
                File.Create(filePath).Close();
            }
            string delimiter = ",";
            string[][] output = new string[][]{
            new string[]{visitDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "," + numVisits} 
            };
            int length = output.GetLength(0);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index]));
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

So to put briefly here is what I need to do:

- Have the console automatically start on the date I started track the website.

Notes:

- The tool grabs the date and amount of visits

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question.

**Option 1:**

Make a request

- Dimension: ga:date
- metric: ga:sessions
- set start date to 2005-01-01 (this is the first date that Google Analytics was launched).
- end date to today.
- filters:   ga:sessions>0
- maxresults:  1

This will return the first date that there is date for the account then you can use that.   [Query Explore example](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253Adate&metrics=ga%253Asessions&filters=ga%253Asessions%253E0&start-date=2005-01-01&end-date=2014-03-06&max-results=1)

**Option 2:**

Request the info from the Mangagment API.   The management api returns the created date of the account.   [Account.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accounts/list)

**Note**:  remember if you grab all this data at once changes are your going to end up with sampled data.  Make sure your requests are small.